# multiple condition loop, while, if

Tags: bash, embedded-linux

here is my problem: I need to move different file names from a common directory into different directory folders. I'm new in Linux, I just made some tests but I'm stuck in this issue. The example is:

these files: moon, sea, monkey, milk

needs to be moved in different specific folders already created so

moon must be moved to /home/moon

sea must be move to /home/sea

and I would solve by using less code as possible. Could you help me in this?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

This is what I did, but I would optimize because I have to repeat this code for each file I need to move by changing the $dirpath for each different file since I don't know how to associate the file I search ($stuff) and the correct directory ($dirpath) where the file needs to be moved.

```
stuff="*Milk*"

if test -n "$(find /volume1/Incoming/ -iname "$stuff")"  
    then  
    dirpath="/volume1/home/My milk"  
    echo -n Action taken file move:" " >/volume1/homes/admin/result  
    find /volume1/Incoming/ -iname "$stuff" -print >>/volume1/homes/admin/result -exec mv {} "$dirpath" \;  
    echo  Destination: $dirpath >>/volume1/homes/admin/result
```

Could you tell me how to improve this code?

Comment: What do you have so far? And please show realistic example of what you want done, if a file needs to be moved to a directory with the same name, you'll only ever have one file in those directories, and you don't actually need conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in moon sea monkey milk
do
  mv /your/dir/$i /home/$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

move to the directory where your files are stored and run the below lines of code.

```
for i in *  
do  
mv $i /home/$i  
done
```